# Color and pagebreaks with footnotes

Tags: color, footnotes

My question is: **is there a way to color text despite that text spilling over into the next page on the output PDF (and with a footnote at the bottom of the first page)?**

I am colour-coding an 80-page text document (converting from LaTeX to PDF using `pdflatex`).

Whether I use the `color` or `xcolor` package, most of my document renders exactly as I want. For example,

`... of that \textcolor{blue}{I myself can only be judge in my own conscience, as I will answer it}, at the great day, to ...`

renders the relevant text in blue. This is true even when that text spills from one page to the next.

However, when there is a footnote at the bottom of the page, the colored text stops prematurely and does not continue on to the next page.

This sounds like the known issue mentioned in the [xcolor manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), section 2.15.2 (p. 30); however, the suggested fix (`\usepackage[fixpdftex]{xcolor}`) "does not support several independent text streams like footnotes", so does not work for my issue.

Does anyone know of a fix which works despite footnotes? Or a different, possibly simpler, color package that avoids this? (The issue occurs for me both with `color` and `xcolor`.)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: actually it's really hard to do this in tex, I assume you are using pdftex? If you make some simplifying assumptions such as "footnotes never split over a page" or "footnotes are not coloured" or ...then it's usually possible to do something

Comment: Thank you, @DavidCarlisle. Yes, I am using `pdftex`. You are right -- I can now see that the issue was caused by the fact that the footnote too was coloured. Mandating that footnotes not be coloured is a bit of a compromise, but not too onerous. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `pdfcolfoot`. It implements an independant color stack for footnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfcolfoot}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]\footnote{\color{red}\lipsum[1-2]}
\textcolor{blue}{\lipsum*[1]}

\end{document}
```

### Output with the package

[image]

### Output without it

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was hoping for. As you say, it works perfectly. (To anyone else reading this: it is part of the oberdiek collection of packages, so bundled with TexLive and MikTex.)

Comment: @ulrikefischer Is there a similar package for hyperlinks?